# Face where there should be no face

Tags: 3d-models, stl, blender

When importing [this .stl file](https://www.file-upload.net/download-14067778/Bmw_Sensor_Halter.stl.html) in Creality Slicer another face appears in the middle when viewed in layered view. This face is not visible in my 3d modeling software Blender. I tried cleaning up the model a bit and to triangulate the faces myself, neither helped and the problem is still there. Also I didn't find anything online.

[image: Normal View]

[image: Layered View]

Answer (score 4):

At the intersection of the top and bottom planes of the cross-piece and the cylinder, there are non-manifold edges. Meshmixer is able to identify this problem but cannot repair it. My slicer, Simplify3D also identifies the faults and prints a solid cylinder between the planes. Prusa Slicer 2 also creates a solid at that location.

As you've indicated that you are the creator, consider to use the [3D printing features](https://daler.github.io/blender-for-3d-printing/printing/3d-print-toolbox.html) within Blender to assist you with repairing the problem locations.

> File ‣ User Preferences (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>)
>   to open the User Preferences menu.
>
> In the Add-ons tab, start typing 3d print into the search bar. Once
>   the “Mesh: 3D Print Toolbox” shows up, click the checkbox on the far
>   right to enable this add-on.
>
> Close the User Preferences window.
>
> In the Tool Shelf, there should be a new 3D Printing tab.

[image: 3d printing tab]